# Chosen not loading ul li until first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I am trying to use chosen against select box.

```
<select  id="customer" style="width:400px;">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

And then

```
  $("#customer").chosenImage();
```

But the problem is chosen UL is not populated until i click on div for first time. How do i load UL directly?

Comment: Will you be having preloaded `options` in the `select`  or any `ajax` request will be performed? It will be good to have some `snippet` or `fiddle` replicating the problem..

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: Hope you are talking about **[this plugin](https://github.com/djgrant/chosen-image)**

Comment: @GuruprasadRao yes chosenImage and i already have populated data

Comment: could you please add appropriate or complete `html`? Like what actual problem this creates? It takes time show options?

Comment: It does not load chosen ul until i click on div

Comment: I feel its a default option from the plugin @Richa.. Bdw, I am still confused why you are so worried about `ul` not getting loaded before click?? What problem it causes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146144/discussion-between-guruprasad-rao-and-richa).